# angular and dropbox can(t get token with code flow

Tags: angularjs, dropbox

i have this snippet:

```
var req = {     
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://api.dropboxapi.com/oauth2/token',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    data: {
        'code': authCode,
        'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
        'client_id': 'my_id',
        'client_secret': 'my_secret',
        'redirect_uri':'http://localhost%3A8080/main'
    }
};

return $http(req).then(function(response){
        console.log(response.status);
        return response;
    }, function(err){
        console.log(err);
    });
```

The can always ends up in a "bad request" because ""No auth function available for given request""

The same data works with tools to send REST requests... so I don't know what I'm missing here...

Can some help?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#oa2-authorize ,  you checked that right ?

Comment: I think your url should be https://api.dropboxapi.com/1/oauth2/token according to https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#oa2-token

Comment: Both /1/oauth2/token and /oauth2/token work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message indicates that the API didn't receive the expected parameters, or at least not in a format it expected. The [documentation for /1/oauth2/token](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#oa2-token) say:

> Calls to /oauth2/token need to be authenticated using the apps's key and secret. These can either be passed as POST parameters (see parameters below) or via HTTP basic authentication. If basic authentication is used, the app key should be provided as the username, and the app secret should be provided as the password.

You seem to be attempting to supply the parameters as JSON though, according to your `Content-Type` header. Try sending them as POST parameters instead.

Comment: This. replaced the content type to `   $http.defaults.headers.post = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'};
` and sent the data in astring. Thanks